# Need to show random picture for behaviour

Tags: java, image, random

Please, forgive my ignorance, as I am new to Java programming.  However, I need to show a picture (at random) for each of the three behaviours listed, below.  Each picture has a designated image - What would be the best method to do so?

```
String whatsUp()
{
double r;
int myNumber;
String behaviour="";
r = Math.random();
myNumber = (int) (r * 3.0)+1;

switch(myNumber)
{
case 1:
behaviour = "reading";
break;
case 2:
behaviour = "surfing the web";
break;
case 3:
behaviour = "interacting with other students";
break;
}
return behaviour;
}
}
```

Comment: Where are the links to your pictures in your code? Also, your random number is going to be anywhere between 1 and 2 million, and I don't think that is what you intended.

Comment: The links are in an images folder within the root file of the project I am working on (i.e. images/image1, 2, 3).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if I was to go into case 1, you would then want it to randomly show one of the three pictures (I am assuming this is so the user could determine whether the two match or not)

Comment: Correct - Case 1 would have its own picture, Case 2 and so forth.  I understand I can set the pictures to display at random, but each behaviour should show its own designated image (if that makes sense).

Comment: Oh I see okay, I am working on the answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your process to get a random number doesn't make a lot of sense. What you'll want to to is create a new random object "r":

```
Random r = new Random();
```

Then you can use this object to create a random number from zero to a certain index. In your case this would be three.

```
int randomNumber = r.nextInt(index); //replace index with three
```

However, this would give the numbers 0, 1, and 2 so you will want to add one to the number.

```
int randomNumber = r.nextInt(index) + 1;
```

This will now give you a random number from one to three.

To get three images into the system you could use ImageIcon or similar method, which I will let you figure out for yourself.

I would then put the ImageIcons inside an ArrayList so that they can be easily accessed like so:

```
ArrayList<ImageIcon> images = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();
 images.add(imageOne);
 images.add(imageTwo);
 images.add(imageThree);
```

Thus, when inside case 1, 2, or 3 you could have a reference to the ArrayList you created with the first random number you you created like this

```
selectedImage = images.get(r); // the random number acts as the index
```

This will not display any image; you will have to work out how to do that yourself, but hopefully this gives you a good idea of where to go from here.